# JavaEE Hibernate - change DB Schema at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I want to access a foreign database (Oralce) using WildFly and Hibernate. I have a DB user who has access to several momentary unknown DB Schemas. How is it possible to dynamically change the DB Schema at runtime? I do not use a Spring Framework and I do not want to use it.

Comment: That's not a possible solution to my problem. I do not use a Spring Framework and I do not want to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by “DB Schema”? The definition of the tables and columns? Or switching between databases? Or do you mean cluster > catalog> schema hierarchy defined by the SQL standard?

Comment: What do you mean by “foreign”

Comment: By foreign, I mean that I want to access a DB that is not mine. The DB comes from another application, but I have to access the database (read only).

Comment: By schema I mean the following
SELECT * FROM **[SCHEMA]**.[TABLE]

Comment: Your last comment is the answer to your question. Plug the text of name of schema into your SQL.

Comment: I did not really want to use native queuys and leave the work to the JPA. Is there no way to influence the schema of the JPA at runtime?

Comment: See [here](https://www.toptal.com/hibernate/build-multitenant-java-hibernate) for one approach